# React loading screen on all routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I understand how I can get a spinner screen with `state` and `componentDidMount()` but how would I go about creating a loading screen in between on all routes without having to write `componentDidMount()` in every component?

My app.js file

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }

  onWaypoint = () => {
    this.child.current.navChangeHandler();
  }

  render() {

    let routes = (
      <Switch>    
        <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Redirect exact to="/" />
      </Switch>
    )

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App" styleName="main-wrapper">
          <Layout>
              {routes}
              <Navigation ref={this.child} />
          </Layout>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}
```

I want to be able to see a spinner in between these routes.

Comment: Route changes are instant - what would the spinner be for?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) wrapper function over a child component. Then, if desired, you can pass a HOC method to the child and have the child invoke the method.

For example:

**Parent:**

```
export default WrappedComponent => {
  class Wrapper extends Component {
    state = { isLoading: true };

    componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
      if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
      }
    };

    doneLoading = () => this.setState({ isLoading: false })

    render = () => (
      <WrappedComponent
        doneLoading={this.doneLoading}
        isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
        {...this.props}
      />
    );
  }
  return withRouter(Wrapper);
};
```

**Child (has access to passed down HOC method/state from within child's `this.props`):**

```
export default class Child extends PureComponent {

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch("someURL")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ list: json }), () => this.props.doneLoading());
  };

  render = () =>
    this.props.isLoading 
      ? <Spinner />
      : <DisplayList list={...this.state.list} />
}
```

The downside is that every child component needs to import `Spinner` and check that `isLoading` is false.

### Limitations

In order for this to work among heavily nested components, you'll most likely want/need to integrate Redux. In addition, you'll need to have a mounted container dispatch an action to update/reset the `isLoading` Redux state upon every route change. Either way, it's not going to be a simple and elegant solution if you want to be DRY.

---

### Example

Working example (this example just has the HOC state being set/unset by a timeout): https://codesandbox.io/s/2zo8lj44pr

**Wrapper.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import Header from "./Header";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";

export default WrappedComponent => {
  class Wrapper extends Component {
    state = { isLoading: true };

    componentDidMount = () => this.setTimer();

    componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
      if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
        this.clearTimer();
        this.setState({ isLoading: true }, () => this.setTimer());
      }
    };

    clearTimer = () => clearTimeout(this.timeout);

    timer = () => this.setState({ isLoading: false }, () => this.clearTimer());

    setTimer = () => (this.timeout = setTimeout(this.timer, 3000));

    render = () => (
      <Fragment>
        <Header />
        {this.state.isLoading
          ? <Spinner />
          : <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
  return withRouter(Wrapper);
};
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Schedule from "../components/Schedule";
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper";

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Wrapper(Home)} />
      <Route path="/schedule" component={Wrapper(Schedule)} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) can help you to achieve this purpose and also have benefit of [code splitting](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-javascript/code-splitting/).

[Code Splitting in React Using React Loadable](https://alligator.io/react/react-loadable/)

[Code Splitting with React and React Router](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-code-splitting/)

Answer (score 0):

My attempt:

```js
return <Switch>
    <Route
        exact
        path={loading ? '*' : '/'}
        component={LoadingRoute} />
    <Route
        path={loginPaths}
        component={LoginLayout}
    />
    <Route
        path={adminPaths}
        component={AdminLayout}
    />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

In this case, neither `loginPaths` nor `adminPaths` has the path `/`, so the default path of loading is `/`. In the case that the root path is important, you can use the `;` path, so it will not match with anything. I'm using `AnimatedSwitch` from [react-router-transition](https://github.com/maisano/react-router-transition/), so the state between transitions are important. And with this, you App say when is loading or not.